# Where to find 'Missing Marketing Icon'

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, icons, xamarin-studio

I published an application to apple app store and I got a message which says that I'm missing marketing icon as I'm using iOS 11.
where can I add this 1024X1024 png marketing icon in xamarin studio?
I'm using xamarin studio 6.3, xcode 9.0

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same issue with Xamarin v.6.3 and xcode 9.0. After long search and long tries, here is how i solve it:

1. Add 1024x1024.png icon to your project. (Make sure the png file dose not have Alpha or transparent). you can use Export option in Preview application of Mac.
2. Open your Storyboard using Xcode.
3. Go to the Assets.xcassets folder.
4. Under Appicon category, you find App Store iOS box.
5. Drag the icon from your images.
6. Save your project in xcode.
7. Go back to your Xamarin and make new build, then submit to Appstore.

Answer (score 4):

Now in IOS 11, we need to add a new icon in our project of size 1024*1024. Also, make sure you are using released version not a beta version.

1. Under the project in Xcode navigate to “Your project -> Images.xcassets->AppIcon"
2. Scroll to the bottom
3. Add a 1024x1024 icon

[image]

Comment: I'm developing my app using xamarin not xcode, xamarin uses xcode for building and for other purposes, and I can't find this marketing icon place

Comment: Solution I found in this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios11/updating-your-app/
Mentioning important thing here
"Store icons (or marketing icons) are no longer managed in iTunes Connect, and instead must be contained as an asset catalog in your app binary, similar to app icons. A 1024 x 1024 store icon in PNG format must be included in an asset catalog for successful submission of iOS 11 apps."

Comment: I did include it in an asset catalog but the problem still exist

Comment: How about the info.plist?

Answer (score 2):

From the post given by [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios11/updating-your-app/#App_Icon), App icons should now be delivered by an Asset Catalog.

[image]

For help with migrating icons from an Info.plist to an Asset catalog, see the [Migrating from Info.plist to Asset Catalogs guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/deprecated/app-icons/#Migrating_from_Info.plist_to_Asset_Catalogs)

Answer (score 2):

I manually modified the application icon information that is part of the asset catalog.  From your project folder navigate to the asset catalog folder and the appiconset folder within that folder. Locate the Contents.json file and edit it.  In the file there is a list of images and you will need to add this text to the list:

```
{
  "filename": "<YourImageFile.png>",
  "size": "1024x1024",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "ios-marketing"
}
```

You will also need to add the file to your project file by adding these lines to the item group that contains your other icon files:

```
<ImageAsset Include="Resources\Assets.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset\YourImageFile.png">
  <InProject>false</InProject>
</ImageAsset>
```

Comment: Big thumbs up to this!
Although my Contents.json did contain my store link, my .csproj did not!

Answer (score 0):

1) Double-click the Info.plist file in the Solution Explorer -> [Your iOS project] and fill the iTunes Artwork:

[image]

2) It problem still existing,update your Xamarin Studio to the latest version and try again

3) Try to use Visual Studio for Mac

*Note: Remember to fill the App Icons for your target devices in the Assets.xcassets also.*
[image]

Comment: I updated xasmarin studio, my screen looks the same as your scrrenshot, there is no way to add `1024X1024` size, how did you do that?

Comment: Did you examine the Info.plist?

Comment: I solved my problem by installing last version of Visual studio for mac. this option doesn't exist in xamarin  studio and VS windows