# Unable to upload iOS app with Application Loader ( ERROR ITMS-90023 )

Tags: xcode, icons

I'm trying to upload an app using Application Loader.

It returns the following errors:

> X description length:723218
>
> X ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
>
> X ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
>
> ! WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing Marketing icon. iOS apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing icon in PNG format. Apps that do not include the Markering icon cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review."

---

I'm using Xcode 9.0.1. The error appeared first in Xcode 9.0. The icons are present in the app of the correct sizes and without alpha channel. The app runs fine in all simulators.

I've also tried uploading an app, which did go through Application Loader two weeks ago, but the error turns up for that app as well. It seems Apple has changed something.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Add marketing icon. Like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46388551/7956211

Comment: i solved this problem by link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885406/4305700

Answer (score 0):

Now in IOS 11, we need to add a new icon in our project of size 1024*1024. Also, make sure you are using released version not a beta version. Also add the missing icons 76x76 and 152*152

1) Under the project in Xcode navigate to “Your project -> Images.xcassets->AppIcon"

2) Scroll to the bottom

3) Add a 1024x1024 icon

[image]

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, I'm using Version 9.0.1 (9A1004). All icons (76x76, 152x152 and 1024x1024) are already in AppIcon. I think the error is caused by something else, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Please check your AppIcon are placed at correct places.Sometimes by mistake, we place wrong size icons in wrong places. Goto “Your project -> Images.xcassets->AppIcon" and check all icons have correct dimensions and placed at correct places.

Comment: I've already checked all icons. They are placed correctly and have the right dimensions. I've also tried with my last app. I changed name and bundle id and uploaded it as the new update. I get the same error even though the icons must be correct, since the upload was accepted two weeks ago. I believe Apple has changed some verification when uploading. The icons look good on all simulators as well.

Comment: It happens the same to me. Recently I've download the latest application loader and I couldn't compile. the same errors. Is your app a phonegap app?