# iOS Build Error: missing file Icon102.png

Tags: ios, build

I have a Xamarin Forms App running on Android and iOS. Everything works fine on a Simulator and on lokal devices.
When I push the Buid to AppCenter, the Android Version gets build without a problem, but the iOS Build alsways fails with the following error:

(_CoreCompileImageAssets target) ->   /Users/runner/runners/2.165.1/work/1/s/O365Info/O365Info.iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon1024.png : error : File not found: /Users/runner/runners/2.165.1/work/1/s/O365Info/O365Info.iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon1024.png [/Users/runner/runners/2.165.1/work/1/s/O365Info/O365Info.iOS/O365Info.iOS.csproj]

```
24 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:01:01.73

### [error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6_6_1/bin/msbuild failed with return code: 1. For guidance on setting up the build definition, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.

### [section]Finishing: Build Xamarin.iOS solution.

In the first builds I didn't even had a Iconset called AppIcon.appiconset (my Iconset was named appiconset1) and the whole project didn't include a file named "Icon1024.png".
I then renamed my Iconset to appioconset and included a file named "Icon1024.png", but I'm still getting the same error.

No ideas, where this error might come from. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Copied From ColeX at:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179775/build-error-with-missing-file-icon1024-png

1. Edit csproj file to remove the bogus entries (just delete them)
2. Ensure that a 1024*21024 png icon (file does not have Alpha or transparent) add into Assets.xcassets
3. Ensure the 1024 file information included in csproj file

Refer

[Where to find 'Missing Marketing Icon'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388146/where-to-find-missing-marketing-icon)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129252/problems-with-missing-appicons-files